# Looking for jQuery solution for planning room rentals

Tags: jquery

I was looking around for a solution to plan the occupation of multiple rooms in a hotel. A normal calendar will be useless because the amount of rooms. I was actually thinking of a Gantt like solution, showing the rentals in a horizontal way and the rooms vertically.

Is there an out-of-the-box solution for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jquery ganttView](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ganttView)

I've used jQuery ganttView before and it works pretty well. It's also very light-weight as the description implies. It can also be used with [Date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) which is excellent.

Comment: Can I plan multiple events on one line? I thought that was the problem with that solution..